C# - Connect to ZKTeco device with SDK
I'm new to ZKTeco devices and I'm trying to make an app that connects to a ZKTeco device to extract access information and store it in a database. However, I'm facing problems understanding how to connect to it directly. With other devices from other manufacturers the SDKs provided a method to establish the connection by specifying the IP address and port of the device on the network. In the case of ZKTeco I cannot see an option to do so in the SDK documentation.
The device I'm currently using is a SpeedFace V3L which seems to be a Push device. I know there are different SDKs for different devices and that the push SDK is a paid one. That said, is it not possible to connect to it just to extract access information using one of the free SDK that ZKTeco provides?
I have tried to understand some of the demos they provide but most of them don't seem to function with my device.
With it being a Push device could I use their web app to connect to it and extract the information using calls to the ZKBio server for example?
